# read from SQL to Button

Tags: vb.net

please help on this issue, i want to read ID from SQL to different button but still i cant able to do it. please help.

this is the code i tried.
this code read same ID in both button instead of different id in different button. see the screenshot for your reference.
[image]

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select Locker_ID from Locker", colnnn)
da.Fill(dt)

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Button2.Text = row.Item("Locker_ID")
    Button1.Text = row.Item("Locker_ID")
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not only have to loop the rows but also the buttons. If you have 2 locker rows, your loop executes the loop body twice. I.e., the first locker id is assigned to both buttons and then the second locker id is assigned to the same buttons again, overwriting the first value.

```vb
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select Locker_ID from Locker", colnnn)
da.Fill(dt)

Dim i As Integer = 1
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Controls("Button" & i).Text = row.Item("Locker_ID")
    i = i + 1
Next
```

This will assign the first `Locker_ID` to `Button1`, the second one to `Button2`, etc.

The `Controls` collection allows you to access the controls by name by using a string as index.

Note that you can change the name of the buttons. If you name the buttons where you want to have the locker id as `btnLocker1`, `btnLocker2`, `btnLocker3` etc. then `Controls("btnLocker" & i).Text = row.Item("Locker_ID")` will automatically select the right buttons.

---

It is advisable to give your controls speaking names. Also, do this before creating event handlers. E.g., nobody knows what `Sub Button17_Click` is supposed to do; however, if you name the button `btnPrint`, the winforms designer will automatically create a Sub named `btnPrint_Click` when you double click the button.

---

See also: [For Each Loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/control-flow/loop-structures#for-each-loops)

Comment: Also worth mentioning is `Controls(),Text` will throw if it's not found.

Comment: sorry i didnt get it clear, u mean like this:

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Controls("Button1, Button2" & i).Text = row.Item("Locker_ID")
            i = i + 1
        Next
This give me error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
PLEASE HELP.

Comment: With `Controls("Button name")`, you can get a button with the given name. In the For Each loop I increment `i`, so that it gets the values 1, 2, 3, ... in turn for each loop. So for the first row `Controls("Button" & i)` gets button `Button1`. For the second row `Button2`, for the 3rd row `Button3` etc. Note that you have to do this for one row at a time, because all the statements inside the loop are repeated once for each row of table `Locker`. E.g., if you have 10 lockers, my code example will automatically set the Text of the buttons `Button1` through `Button10`.

Comment: Olivier sorry to say this but i try so many times but still i cant figure it out. can you just give me one example. please i really need help on this.

Comment: You should be able to replace your code by my code. It assumes that you have buttons named "Button1", "Button2" etc, as many or more as you have lockers.